# Want to use VBScript to run .bat file in a different folder

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I'm trying to run a .bat file using VBScript.  I can get the VBScript to work when executed within the same folder as the .bat, however, I can't figure out how to make it successfully run when outside the folder.

```
Dim shell
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run "C:\Users\js\Desktop\createIndex\createindex.bat"
```

Comment: Try shell.run "C:\\Users\\js\\Desktop\\createIndex\\createindex.bat"

Comment: I just gave that a try and when I ran the script, nothing happened.  When I moved the script back in the folder with the changes you suggested, it ran the .bat as expected.  So, unfortunately, this isn't a fix.

Comment: Try this for now, it may give you an error message. `shell.run "cmd /k C:\Users\js\Desktop\createIndex\createindex.bat"`. I assume your path is correct and has no spaces in it.

Comment: Strange; that should be working. Or at least, I'm managing to call a .bat file via a .vbs file that's in a separate directory. I _did_ notice that the batch file closed very quickly before I added a `pause`, but it still technically worked.

Comment: Perhaps the .BAT itself requires full path(s). This may be pointless without seeing the .BAT script. What can you do in a .BAT or .CMD that you cannot do in a .VBS?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Going out on a limb I would suspect that the batch script requires its own parent folder to be the working directory. You can set the working directory accordingly by changing your code to this:

```
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.CurrentDirectory = "C:\Users\js\Desktop\createIndex"
shell.Run "createindex.bat"
```

---

If the above doesn't help you need to provide more information about what *should* happen and what actually *does* happen. Running the external command/script in visible mode and without automatically closing CMD usually helps with debugging:

```
shell.CurrentDirectory = "C:\Users\js\Desktop\createIndex"
shell.Run "cmd /k createindex.bat", 1, True
```

Comment: The first script you posted worked just as I had hoped it would.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use this script to set the directory to the current working directory of your script. That way whenever the script changes directories it will look for it there instead of hard rooting it to a specific directory.

```
 scriptdir = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
```

This will make any files that it is looking for in that directory available to the script. 
Example : If the file were on the current users desktop.

C:\Users\[Username]\desktop\myfile.vbs

Will become:

scriptdir\myfile.vbs

and if you moved it to a subfolder "subfolder" it would remain

scriptdir\myfile.vbs

even if the script location is different. The "scriptdir" is a placeholder for the folder the active script is running from.

Answer (score 0):

I've 4 simple scripts for what kind of calls.

**call.vbs**

**call_nowait.vbs**

**call_nowindow.vbs**

**call_nowindow_nowait.vbs**

All the 4 has these lines of code in the beginning:

```
ReDim args(WScript.Arguments.Count-1)
For i = 0 To WScript.Arguments.Count-1
  If InStr(WScript.Arguments(i), " ") > 0 Then
    args(i) = Chr(34) & WScript.Arguments(i) & Chr(34)
  ElseIf WScript.Arguments(i) = "" Then
    args(i) = Chr(34) & WScript.Arguments(i) & Chr(34)
  Else
    args(i) = WScript.Arguments(i)
  End If
Next

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' MsgBox Join(args, " ")
```

Plus the last line is different in all 4 scripts:

**call.vbs**

```
objShell.Run Join(args, " "), 1, True
```

**call_nowait.vbs**

```
objShell.Run Join(args, " "), 1, False
```

**call_nowindow.vbs**

```
objShell.Run Join(args, " "), 0, True
```

**call_nowindow_nowait.vbs**

```
objShell.Run Join(args, " "), 0, False
```

For example, the entire command line for the *call_nowindow.vbs* script looks like this:

```
call_nowindow.vbs "C:\Users\js\Desktop\createIndex\createindex.bat"
```

By the way, you can run anything by these scripts, not only just batch files.
This one will create an instance of notepad.exe with out window:

```
call_nowindow.vbs notepad
```

This one will create cmd console with current date and time, and leave the window open:

```
call_nowait.vbs cmd /k echo.%DATE% %TIME%
```